# R: unexpected numeric constant when using the package XML

Tags: r, xml

I'm trying to grab data on Yahoo Finance with the XML package. The url is [here](http://finance.yahoo.com/market-overview/?bypass=true).

It's the home page of Yahoo Finance and I want to grab the prices of commodities:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eDld4.png)

Say, I want to get the number "42.21" I highlighted in the screenshot. The code is here:

```
library(XML)
doc=htmlParse("http://finance.yahoo.com/market-overview/?bypass=true")
getNodeSet(doc,"//span[@class="184"]")
```

But the software returns:

```
Error: unexpected numeric constant in "getNodeSet(doc,"//span[@class="184"
```

Can anyone help me fix this? I've used the very similar method to grab data before but I don't know what's wrong here. Thank you.

Comment: In R like most languages, you need to escape quotes within a string literal or use single quotes outside or inside. Also check page source as those figures are wrapped as text value within `<script>` tags. Most likely, page is rendered with javascript.

Comment: thank you @Parfait